# Socket.io with NGINX upstream configurations

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I had developed a iOS gaming real time application using swift language and I am using Node.Js and Socket.io server technologies, and we have large traffic more now approx 10K users comes at a time, and we are using NGINX web server with upstream feature with multiple ports to manage load balancing, right now we are sending messages to all online 10K users at a time, but 40% users receiving socket event remaining 60% not receiving, so i want to know is my NGINX configuration configured successfully or not ? it`s working with multiple ports or not ? I had attached my ng inx configuration file also /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (path).

Please let me know, why all users are not receiving socket event (message) ?

[nginx configuration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLYlU.png)

Thanks

Comment: Do not post code or config files as an image but as text. And `enter image description here`  is not meant to be left unchanged, it has to explain what the image contains.

Comment: DONE, added image description.

Comment: You have changed the image description. The main point, however, was about that you should not post a screenshot of the config file, instead of that you should add it as text to the question.